sqlfluff:Unrecoverable error in jinja templating
I am running sqlfluff lint on a file and getting error:
L:   1 | P:   1 |  TMP | Unrecoverable failure in Jinja templating: no loader for  
                       | this environment specified. Have you configured your  
                       | variables?  
                       | https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/latest/configuration.html

I have pored over the linked document but can't figure out the problem. Below is a repro.
I have simply 2 files:
.
├── demo.sql
└── modules
    └── grant_privilege_on_integration_to_role.j2

modules/grant_privilege_on_integration_to_role.j2 contains:
{% macro grant_privilege_on_integration(privilege, integration, role) -%}
GRANT {{privilege}} ON INTEGRATION {{integration}} TO ROLE {{role}};;
{%- endmacro %}

demo.sql contains:
{% from 'modules/grant_privilege_on_integration_to_role.j2' import grant_privilege_on_integration %}

when I run sqlfluff lint --dialect snowflake demo.sql I get the error that you see above.
sqlfluff --version returns sqlfluff, version 2.3.5.
Can someone explain how I go about fixing this?

Following a suggestion in an answer below from @don I added a file modules/__init__.py:
.
├── demo.sql
└── modules
    ├── __init__.py
    └── grant_privilege_on_integration_to_role.j2

containing:
def grant_privilege_on_integration_to_role(privilege: str, integration: str, role: str) -> str:
    return "dummy output"

but upon running sqlfluff lint --dialect snowflake demo.sql I still get the same error.

We put the macros with a dummy output in __init__.py to get around this:
def some_macro(
    input_one='', **kwargs
) -> str:
    return f"""
        SELECT 'Thank goodness its' AS friday
        """

See the documentation.

Thank you Don. I tried your suggestion but it didn't work for me. I have changed the  question above accordingly.
